# Facebook autocompletion city key is not the city id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, autocomplete

I am developing an app that will use facebook ad-api to autocomplete city name, however, the city id I get from facebook ad-api is not the same as what I get for the same city from graph-api. For example, pittsburgh, in graph-api, is 11493251851302, which I get from user's current living information. However, when I pull a list of city by ad-api, pittsburgh's key is 2512017. Is there anyway that I can convert between those two different id system? Thank you!